# ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed

Tags: oracle, web-services, plsql

Oracle keeps giving me this error:

> ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed

I trying it with `soap_api`

The code follows:

```
FUNCTION add_numbers (p_int_1  IN  NUMBER,
    p_int_2  IN  NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
AS  
l_request  soap_api.t_request;
l_response  soap_api.t_response;
l_return    VARCHAR2(32767);

l_url          VARCHAR2(32767);
l_namespace    VARCHAR2(32767);
l_method       VARCHAR2(32767);
l_soap_action  VARCHAR2(32767);
l_result_name  VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
l_url         := 'http://192.168.1.23:8080/TestWebservice.asmx';
l_namespace   := 'xmlns="http://192.168.1.23:8080/TestWebservice.asmx"';
l_method      := 'add';
l_soap_action := 'http://tempuri.org/add';
l_result_name := 'return';

l_request := soap_api.new_request(p_method       => l_method,
                            p_namespace    => l_namespace);

soap_api.add_parameter(p_request => l_request,
                 p_name    => 'int1',
                 p_type    => 'xsd:integer',
                 p_value   => p_int_1);

soap_api.add_parameter(p_request => l_request,
                 p_name    => 'int2',
                 p_type    => 'xsd:integer',
                 p_value   => p_int_2);

l_response := soap_api.invoke(p_request => l_request,
                        p_url     => l_url,
                        p_action  => l_soap_action);

l_return := soap_api.get_return_value(p_response  => l_response,
                                p_name      => l_result_name,
                                p_namespace => l_namespace);

RETURN l_return;
END;
```

Comment: Check if l_response is not null before calling get_return_value method

Comment: how can i do that.
l_response Comes from **soap_api**

Comment: `IF l_response IS NOT NULL THEN l_return := soap_api.get_return_value(...); END IF;`.

Comment: its't working :( .......... PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'IS NOT NULL' ........... PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: anther question :  why l_response comes from soap_api as null ?

Answer (score 1):

Review the return name the next line

l_result_name := 'return';

In my case change this and solved!!

l_result_name := 'Return';